# Dynamic columns in one sheet based on another sheet values - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google SpreadSheet, Sheet1 has 3 values. [Duration is calculated by =DATEDIF(StartDate, EndDate, "M")]

[image]

Sheet2 has 2 predefined columns (Col1, Col2) and dynamic columns that need to be appended based on the Duration value.

```
Example 1: 
StartDate = 01-Sep-2016 and EndDate = 30-Nov-2016 
So the Duration is 2
```

[image]

```
Example 2: 
StartDate = 01-Sep-2016 and EndDate = 31-Dec-2016 
So the Duration is 3
```

[image]

As the columns are dynamic, is it possible to set the Columns value based on column and row index instead of hard coded as below code.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sDate = s1.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var sDuration = s1.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var sMonth = Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM");
  var sYear = Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY");
  for (var cell = 1; cell <= sDuration; cell++) { 
      s2.getRange("C1").setValue(sMonth + ", " + sYear);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found 80% of the solution, I just added some corrections to your code to make it works dynamically:

```
function myFunction(){

  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sDate = new Date(s1.getRange("B1").getValue()); // changed to B1 - the start date value, and sDate must be a Date Object, not string.
  var sDuration = s1.getRange("B3").getValue(); // changed to B3 - the duration value
  for (var cell = 0; cell < sDuration; cell++) {  // cell starts from 0
    var sMonth = Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"); // I moved this into FOR loop
    var sYear = Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY"); // I moved this into FOR loop
    s2.getRange(1,cell+3).setValue(sMonth + ", " + sYear); // geting range with row & column value, not with Column name
    sDate.setMonth(sDate.getMonth()+1); // add one month to sDate
  }
}
```

there are comments on the code where I changed. I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified the code in [Change value of cell in same row with google script if column has certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716232/change-value-of-cell-in-same-row-with-google-script-if-column-has-certain-value), it works.

Modified onOpen() is,

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sDate = s1.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var sDuration = s1.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var lastColumn = s2.getLastColumn();
  for (var cell = 3; cell <= lastColumn + sDuration; cell++){
    var currentCell = s2.getRange(1, cell);
    currentCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM") + ", " 
                    + Utilities.formatDate(sDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY"));
    sDate.setMonth((sDate.getMonth() + 1) % 12);
  }
}
```