# Trigger script on non manual change/edit to cell - google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following script to send an email every time a "**No**" changes to "**Yes**" in a particular column.

However this only happens if the cell is manually changed to "**Yes**", typed into a cell. And triggers based on the on edit UI trigger.

But the cell updates based on a formula that references to another sheet where it takes the "**No**" and "**Yes**" from, so there is no manual editing/updating on the cell in this sheet.

How can I get it to send the email without any manual change to cells, only on the change from "**No**" to "**Yes**"

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function sendNotification(e){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Order Details")
  if(e.range.getColumn()==3 && e.value=='Yes'){
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();

  var ordernumber = ss.getRange(row,4).getValue();  //Column D
  var sku = [{}]; sku = ordernumber.toString().split("-")

 var sizewidth = ss.getRange(row,5).getValue();  //Column E
 var sizeheight = ss.getRange(row,6).getValue();  //Column F
 var qty = ss.getRange(row,8).getValue();    //Column H
 var country = ss.getRange(row,10).getValue();  //Column J
 var tube = ss.getRange(row,9).getValue();   //Column I
 var paintingimage = ss.getRange(row,7).getValue();  //Column G
 var orderlink = ('http://testly/Km345TS');



 MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "xxx@gmail.com",
  subject:  country + " New Order No. " + ordernumber, // note the spaces between the quotes...
  //attachment: [file,blob],
  htmlBody: "Hello XYZ,  <br><br>"+
   "Please find order details below. <br><br>"+
    sku[1] + "<br><br>" +
   "Size - Width: " + sizewidth + " x " + "Height: " + sizeheight + "<br><br>"+
   "Quantity - " + qty + "<br><br>"+
   "- It needs to be tube rolled"+ "<br>" +
   "- Shipment to " + country + "<br>" +
   "- Order image is " + paintingimage + "<br><br>" +
   "Please fill in cost and delivery details at this link " + orderlink + "<br><br>" +
   "The order is for a customer from " + country + "<br><br>" +
   "Thanking you, <br>" +
   "ABC",            
                   })
 }
}
```

Update: Solution - a big thank you to Ron.

```
function sendNotification2(){
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var data = sSheet.getRange(2, 1, sSheet.getLastRow(), sSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //get the values of your table, without the header
  var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];

    var send = row[16];  //Column Q
    var emailSent = row[17];   //Column R
    var ordernumber = row[4];  //Column E
    var country = row[10];  //Column K
    var orderlink = ('http:/testly/Khghgy');
    var shipaddress = row[18];  //Column S

 if (send == "Yes"){
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates

 MailApp.sendEmail({
   to:  "xx@gmail.com",
  subject:  country + " Ship Order No. " + ordernumber, // note the spaces between the quotes...
  htmlBody: "Hello XYZ,  <br><br>"+

   "Thanking you, <br>" +
   "ABC",            
    })
  sSheet.getRange(i+2, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I've run a test and it also doesn't trigger when the value of the cell is updated with `importRange()`. I've check the web and found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/trigger-function-when-importrange-is-updated), some triggers " aren't triggered on automatic changes like does that occur to automatic recalculation of import functions and functions like NOW." You can use installable triggers to check the changes of the sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the email triggered on the edit change, you could create a separate function that watches for the edit on the other sheet, and then call the above function to send the email.

Something like:

```
function onEdit(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Other Sheet Name");
  if(e.range.getColumn()==3 && e.value=='Yes'){  //change this if the data setup is different on the other sheet
    sendNotification();
  }
}
```

The issue is that this setup will then send an email to every 'Yes' on the email sheet.  This can be rectified using an 'Email_Sent' indicator (you can look that up - lots of examples available).

**Another option, as I mentioned in [the last question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119951/send-email-when-theres-a-change-in-a-particular-column-on-a-particular-sheet/120042#120042), would be to have the `sendNotification` function triggered every minute, 5 minutes, 10 minutes, or ???  This won't provide immediate emails, but it would be nearly so.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'd prefer the second option, a time trigger, I've tried it, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Here you go - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/100EvxesevhaORwh3C4dsrQ8O6Nw6-ycOMZEkqUpN5Lc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try setting up a time-based trigger?  There weren't any active in the script editor.  I set up one to run every 5 min.

Comment: I had since they weren't working I removed them cause I was get a ton of error notifications

Comment: OK.  As I'm thinking about this, it's occurring to me that the time-based trigger may not work for this situation either.  It will have the same problem as the onEdit, because your `sendNotification` function is looking for specific cells, and if the wrong cell is active, you would be getting no email or email for the wrong item.  It may be better to just use the 'Email_Sent' code.  That will prevent duplicates/errors.

Comment: Would I need to add another column that would say email sent?  Or is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Yes, it would be another column.  As I mentioned, there are MANY examples out there.

Comment: I found this article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716232/change-value-of-cell-in-same-row-with-google-script-if-column-has-certain-value, but I'm not sure how I could use it in my script, I know it should update the "send email" column with "email sent" when column "Order confirmation" changes to "Yes" .

Comment: I've tried using that code in my script, but i'm not sure if I'm on the right path here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179157/discussion-between-ron-kloberdanz-and-user2240778).